# Bootstrap 4 How to change input search with clear button color change using css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

There is default clear button appear using search input below is html block of code

```
<div class="input-group search-style ">
                <input id="Search" class="form-control  border-secondary py-2 " type="search" placeholder="search" style="border-right: none !important;">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn removefocus" type="button" style="border-top: 1px solid gray;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;">
                        <i class="fa fa-search "></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image: please see the output]

default color of clear button is blue. How can i change this color on my search input.

Comment: color is not mention there i am talking about color change of close icon only  no extra divs/icon/image required in my case.

Comment: i want default blue cross to be in red color threads which are mentioned are not helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is to set the close icon's appearance to none, and use a background instead:

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: some-image or svg;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mLoeds3c/1/